# Why is the UIImage variable returning null?

Tags: ios, uiimage, segue

As shown in the log output below, imageFile returns correctly, but image does not

**Here's the code for the segue:**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showBandPhoto"]) {
        NSArray *indexPaths = [self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems];
        BDBPhotoViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [indexPaths objectAtIndex:0];

        PFObject *tempObject = [imageObjectsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"object is %@", tempObject);

        NSString *commentGet = [tempObject objectForKey:@"comment"];
        destViewController.comment = commentGet;

        PFFile *imageFile = [tempObject objectForKey:@"image"];
        NSLog(@"ImageFile is %@", imageFile);
        NSData *data = [imageFile getData];

        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
        destViewController.bandImageName = image;

        NSLog(@"image is %@", image);
```

**Here's the log output:**

```
object is Photos:RvKHQNYMtj:(null)
   album = Promos;
    comment = "Promo Pic 2011";
    image = "PFFile: 0x16d901a0";
    ipadImage = "PFFile: 0x16d88f40";
    thumbnail = "PFFile: 0x16d9d360";
ImageFile is PFFile: 0x16d901a0
 Warning: A long-running Parse operation is being executed on the main thread. 
 Break on warnParseOperationOnMainThread() to debug.
 image is UIImage: 0x16ecfac0
 comment is Promo Pic 2011
 image is (null)
```

Thanks for the quick response. After searching for 3 hours, then posting, I found my mistake 10 minutes later. I wasn't retaining a property properly.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of initWithData will return a nil object if no image could be initialized from the specified data.

You should check if the data stored is actually a valid image, or check the result of `[imageFile getData]` is still valid data.